# How to force AWS ECS migrate containers to another ASG?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, terraform

I'm using user_data to do initial configuration of the hosts used in ECS to run containers. I want to be able to tell AWS ECS to migrate containers to a newly created hosts once I update user_data. How can I do that?

I'm using Terraform for AWS infrastructure deployments.

Comment: We created a [terraform module](https://github.com/MakeMeReach/terraform-aws-ecs/tree/master/lambda_ecs_draining) to handle this with a lambda as stated in [this AWS post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/how-to-automate-container-instance-draining-in-amazon-ecs/). What it will do: - create a lambda and a SNS topic (with correct IAM access rights) - Link the lambda and SNS topic You can then link the SNS topic to the `autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATING` lifecycle hook of your autoscaling group. Now when you change any parameters that should destroy and re-create resources, the lambda wil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think ECS has a built-in way to do this. As a result, it usually requires a fairly tedious & manual process (albeit one that could be scripted). There are a few different ways to do it, but this is typically the simplest one:

1. Make your change to `user_data`.
2. Run `terraform apply`.
3. For each EC2 Instance in your ASG that has the old `user_data`:

   1. Terminate that EC2 Instance. You can do this via the AWS CLI or via the EC2 web console.
   2. After a little while, the ASG will automatically launch a new EC2 Instance, with your new `user_data`, to replace the terminated EC2 Instance.
   3. After a little while, ECS will automatically launch new copies of any ECS Tasks that happened to be running on the terminated EC2 Instance.

Once you have gone through this process, all of the Instances in the ASG will be running the new `user_data`. Note that this can be done with zero-downtime for your ECS Tasks as long as:

1. There are at least 2 copies of each ECS Task, each one on a separate EC2 Instance in your ASG.
2. You wait enough time between terminating EC2 Instances for the ECS Task(s) to relaunch.

If you can't meet those requirements, then you may have some downtime, or you may need to pursue a messier option that involves doubling the size of the ASG, waiting for the new EC2 Instances (which will have the new `user_data`) to deploy in the ASG, doubling the number of ECS Tasks, waiting for those new ECS Tasks to deploy (they will typically deploy onto the new EC2 Instances), and then reducing each by half again (in theory, the old ECS Tasks and old EC2 Instances will be terminated, leaving just the new ones behind).

Comment: If you have scaling methods in place, you can replace `3.` with manually scaling up the asg to `<desired_count>*2`. All new instances will have the new `user_data` and when the cluster is scaled down, ECS will delete old instances and keep the new. "Moving", i.e. restarting, tasks on new machines will happen implicitly, AFAIK

Answer (score 1):

While [Yevgeniy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/483528/yevgeniy-brikman)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39960511/2291321) is correct in that there's no way to get Terraform to directly migrate containers to new instances in the event the instances are recreated there is a much cleaner option available to you using Terraform's resource [lifecycle configuration](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#lifecycle).

Assuming you are using autoscaling groups to back your ECS hosts you can do something like this:

```
data "aws_ami" "ubuntu" {
  most_recent = true
  filter {
    name = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/ebs/ubuntu-trusty-14.04-amd64-server-*"]
  }
  filter {
    name = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["paravirtual"]
  }
  owners = ["099720109477"] # Canonical
}

resource "aws_launch_configuration" "as_conf" {
  name_prefix = "terraform-lc-example-"
  image_id = "${data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id}"
  instance_type = "t1.micro"

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "bar" {
  name = "${aws_launch_configuration.as_conf.name}"
  launch_configuration = "${aws_launch_configuration.as_conf.name}"

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

(taken from Terraform's [launch configuration docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/launch_configuration.html))

Now, when the launch configuration changes, for example if either the user data or the AMI being used changes, this will force Terraform to create a new launch configuration which in turn forces a new autoscaling group due to the dependency on the name.

As Terraform is using the `create_before_destroy` lifecycle configuration it will create the new launch config and ASG before destroying it. In the above simple setup the ASG will return as completed as soon as a single instance is deemed healthy by AWS.

Unfortunately that only shows when the EC2 instance is healthy and not that it's successfully running tasks. As mentioned in the comments to this answer ECS won't autobalance the tasks to new instances in the cluster and so Terraform will then destroy the instances that are running ECS tasks in the old ASG before ECS can reschedule them on to the new ASG instances causing an outage.

To work around this (and to also allow for instances to fail and be replaced generally in a nicer way) you can use [ASG lifecycle hooks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/AutoScalingGroupLifecycle.html#as-lifecycle-hooks) to perform some action when an instance is marked for termination but before it is actually terminated.

There's a nice [AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/how-to-automate-container-instance-draining-in-amazon-ecs/) about doing exactly this and has some [example Lambda code] that responds to the hook to drain the container instances that are marked for termination before completing the lifecycle hook which will then allow the ASG to terminate the instances. Having drained the container instances, ECS will automatically reschedule the minimum number of healthy tasks on to the non draining instances (in the new ASG).

If your ECS tasks are registered to a load balancer the tasks will be deregistered by ECS from the load balancer once a new set of tasks are running and then the tasks will remain for the duration of the load balancer's connection drain timeout period.

Comment: Have you actually tried this approach? AFAIK, if you try it, it will either cause a total outage of all your ECS services, or fail entirely. That's because Terraform will create a new ASG (thanks to the `create_before_destroy` param), but ECS will have NO reason to deploy anything on it. Therefore, that new ASG will be empty, and the old one will either be killed (taking all your ECS services with it) or, if you try the ELB healthcheck trick, the `apply` command will fail since nothing is being deployed on the new ASG and therefore, nothing is registering with the ELB.

Comment: I've knocked up a few dummy POCs along these lines but we're not using Docker in production right now. To make this work you do need to have the userdata script join the ECS cluster and then start the task using something like `aws ecs start-task --cluster $cluster --task-definition cadvisor:1 --container-instances $instance_arn --region $region` (taken from https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-an-amazon-ecs-task-on-every-instance/) but yeah otherwise ECS will only move the tasks to the new instances once the old instances are destroyed.

Comment: I have tried that approach and Yevgeniy is correct. It causes the full outage of ECS cluster since ECS doesn't migrate to the new ASG ahead of time. The possible workaround could be to set some ENV variable in ECS task definition containing the name of ASG. That would make ECS make the current tasks INACTIVE and migrate to spare servers. However I don't think it will all happen in a proper order / required amount of time.

Comment: @Maklaus sorry for the delay but I've just updated my old answer with a way to do this nicely with automation. The AWS blog post is pretty useful although I found the provided code for the Lambda function a bit wonky so rewrote that for my new company. Unfortunately it's not open source but it largely follows the same principles that are in the AWS blog post. I've tested it a bunch and not found any issues with the approach and it also has the nice side effect that if an instance running ECS tasks fails health checks or the underlying host is being replaced then it will safely drain the tasks.